# Python module github3 is not working with ansible

Tags: python, ansible, github3.py

I'm trying to use the ansible module github_release that use the python module github3.py.

The machine that I need run the playbook don't have permission to access the internet so I downloaded (pip download github3.py) then in other machine I inslated (pip install ./*.whl).

I'm sure that the python module is instaled:

```
$ pip show github3.py
Name: github3.py
Version: 1.3.0
Summary: Python wrapper for the GitHub API(http://developer.github.com/v3)
Home-page: https://github3.readthedocs.io
Author: Ian Stapleton Cordasco
Author-email: graffatcolmingov@gmail.com
License: 3-clause BSD
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: python-dateutil, uritemplate, requests, jwcrypto
Required-by:
```

But my playbook have the same error:

```
TASK [Get latest release from repository] ***********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [vg1200yr.dc.sedc.internal.vodafone.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Missing required github3 module (check docs or install with: pip install github3.py==1.0.0a4)"}
```

Any idea why my playbook can find the github3 module?

Comment: ansible 2.7.5
Python 2.7.5

Comment: Are ansible and github3.py installed the same way into the same site-packages?